What is a Pisa Word™?
This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by JLee with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.
If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Pisa Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.



Pisa Word™
not a Pisa Word™




milk
water


limp
agile


feed
food


turn
right


spoon
fork


ollie
stan


plonk
drop


film
show


hill
mountain


knoll
dune


bad*
good


him*
her



* is a special Pisa word, I call it a straight Pisa Word™.
Hint:

 Leonardo

Second Hint:

 


Just to check, are you sure that 'him' is a Pisa word? There's a pretty appropriate pattern that fits all of the words in the LH column and none in the right with the exception of that one word... Am happy to be wrong but thought it worth checking! Thanks.

@Stiv, I am pretty sure 'him' is a Pisa Word, but I will double check this evening, just to be sure. Your comment makes me curious about your solution ;) Could you explain the 'Pisa' as well?

Well, if you can't check it immediately then by its nature the rule is very unlikely to be the one I have in mind (for reasons I can share later to avoid any potential spoilers for now)... :)

@Stiv, I have double checked it :)

I believe the answer has something to do with the Fibonacci sequence

A Pisa Word can be determined as follows:

 Convert with A1Z26, treat the resulting numbers as indices in the Fibonacci Sequence, then shade the resulting numbers in the "fibonacci square tiling". If all sequential numbers are connected, it is considered a Pisa Word. Otherwise it is not.

Example:

 (The representations below use the indices rather than the fibonacci numbers for simplicity. It also uses smaller rectangles at one point so it can fit into an image, without losing its properties, i.e. neighboring "squares")Milk (Pisa Word):Fork (not a Pisa Word):

A straight Pisa Word

 is a Pisa Word where the shape appears to be straight. Example for "bad":

Decoding the hints:

 Hint 1 refers to Leonardo of Pisa, AKA Fibonacci.I haven't fully decoded hint 2 to be honest, but I got the word "square" out of it, which was enough: "equals" + "quarter" + (???) - LT = "equa(l)squar(t)er" = "equasquarer" = "(equa) square (r)"Credit to M Oehm: (E->S)QUA(-l) RES(-t) = "SQUARES", where the first E is Ceasar-shifted by 14


Which clue made it a wrong answer?

Actually, this is the correct answer. Why did you think it was a wrong answer? Also, your first explanation of a straight Pisa word is correct as well.

@Lezzup I don't see how port is not a Pisa Word?

Ah, finally! For what it's worth, I think the rebus in the second hint is rot13((R->F)DHN(-y) ERF(-g), jurer gur svefg R vf Prnfne-uvsgrq ol kvi), which doesn't change your answer to it.

@LukasRotter, the R (18) and the T (20) are not connected. Every sequential number should be connected.

@MOehm, correct on the rebus part! :)

And small final note: A straight Pisa word is not exactly where the shape appears straight, it's more where the the letters are in a straight line.

Not sure why Pisa, or what straight means using this definition, so this is likely incorrect, however, the examples (counterexamples) all appear to conform with (break) the rule that:

 PisaTM words have letters confined to a stretch of less than twelve letters of the alphabet.

 The largest stretch covered by a provided example is 11 letters:
 "ollie" -- e-o

 ...while the smallest stretches covered by provided counterexamples are 12 letters:
 "agile" -- a-l
 "food" -- d-o
 "good" -- d-o

Maybe I'm falling for a red herring here as my instinct is that it has something to do with:

 leaning!


Good try, however, this is more of a coincidence, rather than the solution. To give an extra counter example that's not yet in the list: port is not a Pisa Word.
